# Add multiple linearLayouts inside another LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I'm having trouble in my Android application. I need add LinearLayouts inside another linearlayout. I'm using inflation. I'm trying to explain better.

```
 __________________________________________________
|                                                  |
|                                  BUTTON PLUS 1   |
|   __________________________________________     |
|   |                layout1   Button Plus 2  |    |
|   |    ______________btnRemove1________     |    |
|   |    |                       layout2 |    |    |
|   |    |                               |    |    |
|   |    |_____________btnRemove2________|    |    |
|   |_________________________________________|    |   
|                                                  |
|   __________________________________________     |
|   |             layout1  Button Plus 2      |    |
|   |    ______________btnRemove1________     |    |
|   |    |                       layout2 |    |    |
|   |    |                               |    |    |
|   |    |_____________btnRemove2________|    |    |
|   |_________________________________________|    |
|                                                  |
|__________________________________________________|
```

My objective is: When I click on button plus1 add the layout1. When I click in button plus2 add the layout 2 inside layout1. My problem is that I need this a multiple times and the layouts with different id's.

When I click on btnRemove1 I need to remove the layout1 and layout2 simultaneously. When I click btnRemove2 I need to remove layout2.

Here is my code

```
 //Button plus 1    
      case R.id.se_ibAddAddressPostal:
        LayoutInflater inflaterAddressPostal = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout addressPostal = (LinearLayout)inflaterAddressPostal.inflate(R.layout.socio_form_structured_postal, null);
        LinearLayout lLayoutAddressPostal;
        lLayoutAddressPostal = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentAdressPostal);
        lLayoutAddressPostal.addView(addressPostal);

        break;

    //Button plus 2
      case R.id.sfsp_ivMoreAddressPostal:
        ImageButton imbtMoreAddress = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sfsp_ivMoreAddressPostal);
        imbtMoreAddress.setVisibility(imbtMoreAddress.INVISIBLE);

        LayoutInflater inflaterAddressPostal2 = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout addressPostal2 = (LinearLayout)inflaterAddressPostal2.inflate(R.layout.socio_form_structured_postal2,null);
        LinearLayout lLayoutAddressPostal2;
        lLayoutAddressPostal2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentAdressPostal);
        lLayoutAddressPostal2.addView(addressPostal2);
        break;
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo! Welcome to SO. You have come up with a nice app idea. But you will have to take a step and work to implement it. Share with us some code what you have written or at what point you failed to achieve it. Everyone is here to help you.

Comment: I guess you are trying to re-implement ExpandableListView. It's a fully customizable element which shows sublists each time you tell it to.

Comment: I update my question. What I need is to add a layout1. When I click in button plus2 i need to insert a layout1 inside layout1. I need this multiple times and diferent id's on layouts

Comment: You can achieve this by <including> layouts and setting visibility as required.

Comment: My problem is that when i click in button plus 2 in first layout1 he add layout2 below the second layout1. My problem is with the id because I add the same everytime and i don't know how i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On possible way is to set the Tag value on the layouts and the button as you add them. Place the layouts in a Map based on the tag. Then use the tag when the button is clicked to fetch the Layout from the map and remove it.  The tag is an internal marker never shown on the UI.

Comment: Hy Kaediil. Thanks for yout reply. Can you show me an example how I can do this with tag value? Thanks

Comment: Hi again Kaediil. I resolved my problem. I used tags values. Thanks for yout help. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi Christipher. Thanks for your reply. Can you show me an example of how i can do this with a ExpandableListView? Thanks

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/